# What is $I$ in the noise described in the paper "Parameter Space Noise for Exploration"?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, notation

In the paper [Parameter Space Noise for Exploration](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.01905.pdf), the authors describe the noise that they add to the parameter vector as:

$$
\tilde{\theta} = \theta + \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2I)
$$

is $I$ simply the identity matrix, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since $\tilde{\theta}$ is a vector, to define its distribution one needs a [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix). Here $I$ is the identity matrix, which means that the noise has a zero-mean normal distribution with standard deviation $\sigma$, and different components of this noise are uncorrelated.